# LINQ conversion issue

Tags: c#, linq, type-conversion

I'm new to LINQ and I'm having some problems with conversions. I must write a method that finds all students that have their first name alphabetically before their last name. Here's my code:

```
static Student[] FindAllFirstNameBeforeSecond(Student[] students)
{
    Student[] newStudents =
        from student in students
        where student.FirstName.CompareTo(student.LastName) < 0
        select student;

    return newStudents;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ConsoleApplication2.Student>'
to 'ConsoleApplication2.Student[]'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Can I get some tips on what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq query returns result of `IEnumerable<Student>` type. You should convert it to array:

```
static Student[] FindAllFirstNameBeforeSecond(Student[] students)
{
   IEnumerable<Student> newStudents =
        from student in students
        where student.FirstName.CompareTo(s.LastName) < 0
        select student;

    return newStudents.ToArray();
}
```

BTW lambda syntax is more compact in this case:

```
static Student[] FindAllFirstNameBeforeSecond(Student[] students)
{
    return students.Where(s => s.FirstName.CompareTo(student.LastName) < 0)
                   .ToArray();
}
```

Also you can use `s.FirstName < s.LastName` and `Array.FindAll` (if you want result as array):

```
static Student[] FindAllFirstNameBeforeSecond(Student[] students)
{
    return Array.FindAll(students, s => s.FirstName < s.LastName);
}
```